# Google Cloud Service Accounts with Viewer access can perform write operations using appengine remote api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created a service account and gave it Viewer access in **IAM**. Downloaded **p12** key for the service account and used it to access Cloud Project using `remote_api`. Even though only Project Viewer access is granted, I can update data-store entities using the `remote_api`.

Is this a bug or expected behavior? If it is expected, how can I give read only access via `remote_api` to the Cloud Project?